# Cold Fusion Output not displaying

Tags: coldfusion

I created a web page to compute Dollars and Cents. In our assignment we had a few values that we had to assign such as Pennies = 23; Nickels = 8; Dimes = 34 and Quarters =12. We need to enter the ColdFusion statements to display the resulting values in the second Column. Format the Total output as currency.

I created the table but when I run it in the URL it only shows up #Dollarformat(Pennies)#

What can I do to display the number.

```
<!---Add code to initial variables--->

<cfset Pennies = 23>
<cfset Nickels = 8>
<cfset Dimes = 34>
<cfset Quarters = 12>


<!---Add code to perform calculation--->

<cfset Total_In_Cents = Pennies*1+Nickels*5+Dimes*10+Quarters*25>
<cfset Total = Total_In_cents * 100>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Kitchen Sink Model 2123</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
<table align="center" width="200" border="center">
  <tr>
    <th allign"center" colspan="2">Coin Counter Results
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="right">Pennies:</td>
  <td align="right"><cfoutput>#Dollarformat(Pennies)#</cfoutput></td>
  </tr>
  <td align="right">Nickels:</td>
  <td align="right"><cfoutput>#Dollarformat(Nickels)#</cfoutput></td>
  </tr>
  <td align="right">Dimes:</td>
  <td align="right"><cfoutput>#Dollarformat(Dimes)#</cfoutput></td>
  </tr>
  <td align="right">Quarters:</td>
  <td align="right"><cfoutput>#Dollarformat(Quarters)#</cfoutput></td>
   </tr>
  <td align="right">Total(Cents):</td>
  <td align="right"><cfoutput>#Dollarformat(Total_In_Cents)#</cfoutput></td>
   </tr>
  <td align="right">Total:</td>
  <td align="right"><cfoutput>#Dollarformat(Total)#</cfoutput></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. Notice it runs perfectly when tested on [trycfm.com](http://trycf.com/gist/ef0c8f3910180cc376a8/acf2016?theme=monokai)? If you are seeing the literal cfml code, ie `#Dollarformat(Pennies)#`, that means it is not being evaluated properly by the CF server. Either you are not loading the `.cfm` script correctly or perhaps your CF server is misconfigured. Have you run *any* .cfm scripts successfully?

Comment: Maybe I am not loading it correctly. to pass a value in a url is it just .cfm?pennies = 4

Comment: Do you see all of the ColdFusion Code or just what you are trying to output? If it is the former, it sounds like you do not have your web server configured correctly. Also, your logic is flawed. There is no need for `<cfset Total = Total_In_cents * 100>` since you are already getting the total number of cents in the line before. There is also no need for `pennies*1`, just use `pennies`

Comment: @Eric1294 - Yes, but you still did not say whether you have been able to run any CFML code successfully. Like Scott and I mentioned, if you are just seeing ALL of the cfml code, then the web server may not be configured properly. Also, to clarify when I said "There is nothing wrong with it." I meant there is nothing in the CFML code that would prevent it from producing *output*. Once you have that part working, you should review the logic to verify it actually produces the *correct* output (it may not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a simple test to ensure your server is processing ColdFusion. Write a file called mytest.cfm with this code.

```
<cfset pennies = 23>
<cfoutput>#pennies#</cfoutput>
```

This will help your debugging to eliminate any complex code problems.

If you see "23" when you are running this, then your server is processing ColdFusion and something else is wrong, but like Leigh and Scott said in the comments I suspect your server is not processing ColdFusion, which would be confirmed if you see "#pennies#" or all of the code. If this is the case then you need to fix that (a separate question / problem) before answering your code, which looks like it would work, though Scott does point out some extra code help that improves the logic.